# ksh93 esc-esc complation

Tags: ksh

Does anyone know how to set esc-esc completion? I've installed ksh93 from ports on FreeBSD.

set -o vi NOR set -o viraw have any effect

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `set -o vi` then `esc` `\` will provide completion.  If you want to use esc-esc, then try `set -o emacs`

Comment: Definitely try out `Esc ` + `\ `.

Answer (score 1):

Odd that I cannot add a comment to the other 'Answer'? And apparently I asked the above question as an unregistered user- *sigh*.

It appears that the following shell flavors all behave differently:

sh/bourne, hp-ux, (esc-esc file/dir completion)

ksh93 ('esc \' file/dir completion)

pdksh ('esc-esc' file/dir completion)